# In C, Migrate memory to a NUMA node

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, numa

I am developing a NUMA application and I need to migrate big arrays from a node (the node where they are actually created) to another node.

I can't use the `numa_alloc_onnode()` function because I need to have shared memory between the process who allocates memory and its child.

The situation is the following:

I have this array (which dimension is equal to the number of NUMA nodes) of (BIG) node* array, where node* is a typedef of a struct:

```
node** overall_trees;
```

i-th node* array have to be in the i-th NUMA node.

What I have done is:

```
overall_trees[i] = mmap(NULL,(1+number_of_nodes)*sizeof(node), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
numa_move_pages(0, (int) (1+number_of_nodes)*sizeof(node) / PAGE_SIZE, &overall_trees[i],  &i, &status, MPOL_MF_MOVE);
```

but `numa_move_pages()` returns -1.

Actually this is the first time in which I am dealing with NUMA allocation and maybe what I am trying to do is totally wrong. If a completely different solution is possible, feel free to expose it.

Thank you

Comment: What you're doing is similar to what `numa_alloc_onnode` does but is missing the `mbind` step (which `numa_alloc_onnode` does for you). Have you tried doing the alloc in the parent process and _then_ doing the `fork`? Then, I think, the child will have the correct/same numa policy for the region. (i.e.) `numa_alloc_onnode` would work for your use case. If it were me, I'd stick with libnuma as it's easier. I did numa stuff for a production system, pre-libnuma--yecch! If you [still] need to roll your own, I'd pull the libnuma source and use it as a reference

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. The problem I had by using `numa_alloc_onnode()` is that the memory is protected by Copy On Write after the fork(). When a process (the parent of one of the childs) writes a memory location, that have to be shared for the program logic, it is replicated on another physical address and so other processes doesn't see the new value. The behavior is similar to what `mmap` does if I don't use the MAP_SHARED flag.

Comment: You really shouldn't write logic in English; that's what your code is for, and your code will always be shorter (and less frustrating for us to reproduce, and more likely for us to spot errors in) than the equivalent English explanation. Focus on producing an MCVE, instead!

Comment: If `MAP_SHARED` makes a difference, then the children are doing their own `mmap`. Like I said, have the parent do the [single] alloc/mmap and have the children inherit it. `mmap` [or numa] will _not_ guarantee a _physical_ address. The kernel may steal a physical page for an unrelated process [and give back in a _different_ physical slot--and may do this 100 times/sec if it wishes]. Setting a numa policy just guarantees alloc from a given node, but it can be _any_ physical slot on that node